# Saving data in AppDelegate in NSUserdefaults but getting blank when retrieved on other view controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsuserdefaults

I am trying to store a value in `AppDelegate` in `NSUserDefaults`. 
It gets stored successfully, but when I try to fetch the same value from `NSUserDefaults` it returns blank. I have tried finding the solution and implementing all that I could get but still not able to find the correct reason for this blank value.
Kindly check the code and help me to resolve this issue. Thanks in advance!

AppDelegate

```
-(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string{
     if([self.element isEqualToString:@"client_login"]){
          self.currentValue = string;
         [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:self.currentValue forKey:@"client_login"];
        //  NSLog(@"defaults value %@",[defaults valueForKey:@"client_login"]);
          //[defaults synchronize];
     }
     else{
         NSLog(@"currentValue value is blank");
     }

}
```

ViewController

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
   // [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKey:@"client_login"];
    _loginLbl.text =[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKey:@"client_login"];

    NSLog(@"%@", [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] dictionaryRepresentation]);

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}
```

Logs

```
XMLParsingDemo[3549:162060] {
    AKLastIDMSEnvironment = 0;
    AddingEmojiKeybordHandled = 1;
    AppleITunesStoreItemKinds =     (
        "itunes-u",
        movie,
        ringtone,
        album,
        "software-update",
        booklet,
        tone,
        "music-video",
        song,
        podcast,
        software,
        "podcast-episode",
        wemix,
        eBook,
        artist,
        mix,
        document
    );
    AppleKeyboards =     (
        "en_US@sw=QWERTY;hw=Automatic",
        "emoji@sw=Emoji",
        "en_US@sw=QWERTY;hw=Automatic"
    );
    AppleKeyboardsExpanded = 1;
    AppleLanguages =     (
        en
    );
    AppleLanguagesDidMigrate = 15B87;
    AppleLocale = "en_US";
    ApplePasscodeKeyboards =     (
        "en_US@sw=QWERTY;hw=Automatic",
        "emoji@sw=Emoji",
        "en_US@sw=QWERTY;hw=Automatic"
    );
    NSInterfaceStyle = macintosh;
    NSLanguages =     (
        en
    );
    PKKeychainVersionKey = 4;
    "client_login" = "\n    ";
}
```

Comment: Add `[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];` after you store values in user defaults

Comment: Nothing happened,it is till showing blank .

Comment: check if you have any sting value in "self.currentValue"

Comment: ya,its there ..the same thing doesn' happen if I put save static value in NSUserdefaults ,say@"abc" but it happens if I take the string value from method.In string case,it shows data when it is on appdelegate but shows blank when fetched on Viewcontroller.

Comment: Try this code in your viewDidLoad()  dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, 10 * NSEC_PER_SEC), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
       _loginLbl.text =[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKey:@"client_login"];
    });
And tell me if you get anything.

Comment: @sharad chauhan,tried,nothing happened it still shows blanks.

Comment: Your code snippet  response is blank `"client_login" = "\n    "`!

Comment: @ Tubelight,its on the view controller side but on the appdelegate side it has values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The possible reason for this problem is your viewDidLoad() is getting called before you get any value in `-(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string` this method gets updated. So you may be accessing a value before you set anything to that.

Possible workaround could be to use Notifications. In you appDelegate post a notification when your `-(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string` gets called and add an observer in your viewcontroller. After notification got fired try to access the value and update your label on main thread.

In appdelegate, write this in your `-(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string`:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] 
        postNotificationName:@"TestNotification" 
        object:self];
```

In your viewController viewDidLoad():

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
        selector:@selector(receiveTestNotification:) 
        name:@"TestNotification"
        object:nil];
```

In viewController only write the function :

```
- (void) receiveTestNotification:(NSNotification *) notification
{
    // [notification name] should always be @"TestNotification"
    // unless you use this method for observation of other notifications
    // as well.

    if ([[notification name] isEqualToString:@"TestNotification"])
        NSLog (@"Successfully received the test notification!");
}
```

In this method update your label.

**The Actual Problem**

The problem was in :

```
-(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string{
    NSLog(@"^^^^^^^^^ %@", _selectedElement);
    if([_selectedElement isEqualToString:@"client_login"]){
       NSLog(@"Came here: %@, %@",_selectedElement, string);
       [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]setValue:string forKey:@"login"];


    }
    else{
       [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]setValue:string forKey:@"login"];
     }
    NSLog(@"value stored in defaults is %@",[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]objectForKey:@"login"]);
}
```

Here the if condition was true for two times, first time string variable has the correct value but 2nd it is whitespaces with new lines.

So the modified function is :

```
-(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string{
     if([_selectedElement isEqualToString:@"client_login"]){

          NSString *trimmedString = [string stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:
                                     [NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];
          if ([trimmedString isEqualToString:@""]){
          }else{
               [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]setValue:string forKey:@"login"];
          }

     }

}
```

Comment: Now its not calling the selector method on Viewcontroller.

Comment: when this -(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string is getting called ?

Comment: This gets called in correct order in appdelegate ,fills the defaults and then view did load is called.

Comment: So that function is getting called and you are not getting any notificatrions ?

Comment: can you tell me exactly me when parser function is getting called ?

Comment: after did finish launching in appdelegate

Comment: if([self.element isEqualToString:@"client_login"]){
          self.currentValue = string;
         [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:self.currentValue forKey:@"client_login"];
        //  NSLog(@"defaults value %@",[defaults valueForKey:@"client_login"]);
          //[defaults synchronize];
     }

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/159658/discussion-between-sharad-chauhan-and-prez).